# Detecting anomalies question

Tags: data-preprocessing, anomaly-detection

This would be a **data cleaning** question, but I guess there are many related phrases and for sure one of them may be **anomaly detection**.

If I have a single feature say **height of humans**.

**Question**: If I say that everything outside of [Q1-1.5⋅IQR,Q3+1.5⋅IQR] range is an anomaly is this sufficient so that I can say *I have a model for anomalies detection for this particular feature*?

I am not familiar what kind of [models for anomaly detection exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) since Wikipedia is not particularly wordy on that subject but I guess you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I updated my question to point more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, interquartile range is a simple and in many cases effective anomaly/outlier detection model. The choice of how many IQRs (1.5 in your example) is a hyperparamter, and may be tuned to have the desired balance of false positive/negatives.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I actually asked [dono question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/509268/how-anomaly-imputation-influences-the-test-error) where this conclusion is valuable part of proving that I have the model to describe anomalies. But it was not to obvious for some commenters. I would not accept yet this answer because there may be some different points of view. So I will postpone for a week or 100+ views. You may add if you know different models for anomaly detection if such exists but not super important.

Comment: A dono question? I tried to follow the link but it gave a 404

Comment: No wonder since it is deleted. Only admins and I can see it.